# Dart Game Calculating

Tags: php, permutation

I haven't been able to find any scripts or code for darts, so I've been writting my own if anyone knows of a site that has these please let me know (I've searched multiple ways with no luck).

I'm trying to make a script for a dart game (301/501) that will calculate what to shoot at to finish a game. The game ends when you hit an exact score with the darts (3, 2 or 1) and the last dart is a double, (eg. score is 170, could hit 2 triple 20s (2*60), and a double bulls eye (2*25).

I started writing a script that looped through the values and pulled the first values that added up. I wrote this incorrectly/inefficiently though because 1. I looped it three times (even though only 1 or 2 darts might be necessary), and 2. I only outputted the first set of values to shoot at, not all values.

```
Example:
Score 50
 1. double bull (25)
 2. 20 + double 15
 3. 20 + 20 + double 5
 4. 16 + 8 + double 13
 5. double 12 + double 12 + double 1
 6. triple 15 + 1 + double 2
 7. etc.
```

Here's what I started with:

```
$score = $_GET['score'];
if ($score > 170) {
    die('No Outs');
}
$possdarts = array();
$possdartstext = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++) {
    for ($a = 0; $a < 60; $a++) {
        if (($score - $a) >= 0)  {
            $possdarts[] = $a;
            if(($x == 2) && ($a % 2 == 0)) {
                $outs[] = $a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Update code now goes through all values but doesn't check if value is possible on the second dart.

    <table border="1">
    <?php
    for ($x=60; $x>0; $x--) {
     for ($xx=60; $xx>0; $xx--) {
      for ($xxx=50; $xxx>0; $xxx = $xxx - 2) {
       if ($xxx == 48) {
        $xxx = 40;
       }
       echo '<tr>
         <td>' . $x . '</td>
         <td>' . $xx . '</td>
         <td>' . $xxx . '</td>
         <td>' . ($xxx + $xx + $x) .     '</td> 
        </tr>';
      }
     }
    }   
    ?>
    </table>`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close although it is not in order and duplicates will occur.

```
$score = $_GET['score'];
if ($score >170 || $score <=1 ) { 
        $message = 'No outs possible';
    } else {
        for ($x=60; $x >= 0; $x--) {
            if (
                $x <= 20 || 
                $x == 50 || 
                $x == 25 || 
                ($x % 3 == 0) || 
                ($x <= 40 && 
                ($x % 2 == 0)
                )
                ) {
                /*
                if it is less than 20 or equal to, because 20 - 1 on board, 
                if it is less than or equal to 40 and divisible by 2 because it could be a double
                if it is divisible by 3 because it could be a triple
                if it is a double or single bull, no point in checking the double for 60-51 
                */
                for ($xx=60; $xx >= 0; $xx--) {
                    if (
                            $x <= 20 || 
                            $x == 50 || 
                            $x == 25 || 
                            ($x % 3 == 0) || 
                            ($x <= 40 && 
                            ($x % 2 == 0)
                            )
                        ) {
                        for ($xxx=50; $xxx > 0; $xxx = $xxx - 2) {
                            if ($xxx == 48) {
                                $xxx = 40;
                            }
                            $xxxdis = ($xxx / 2) . ' Double';
                            if (($xxx + $xx + $x) == $score) {
                                echo $x . ', ' . $xx . ', ' . $xxxdis . "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: An output from score 50 will give: 48, 0, 1 Double -  45, 3, 1 Double - 45, 1, 2 Double - 42, 6, 1 Double. You say it's not in order - how would you like the output to be? Give an example of the first 5 or so.

Comment: Just a tip: You really should use variablenames that mean something, not just append a letter to it ($x, $xx, $xxx, $xxxx says absolulety nothing and is hard to read)

Answer (score 0):

I would try do something like this: (You have to add with triples also, but this is how I would start...) You'll have to have much memory available for using arrays... It eats up a lot. I tried with 170 and php got exhausted... memory limit. You should be **AWARE** of that. It's not really a problem if your server allows it.

```
<?php
$score = 50;

if ($score >170 || $score <=1 ) { 
        $message = 'No outs possible';
    } else {

        $outs = array();

        //Create an array with values from 0 to {value of $score}
        for($v=0;$v<$score;$v++) {
            $outs[] = $v;
        }

        // Get combinations of values (like 0 0 1, 0 0 2, 0 0 3 etc with space between values)
        $combinations = getCombinations($outs,3);

        //Create an array when combinations are equal to set score

        $ascArr = array();      
        $possibleOuts = array();
        foreach($combinations as $key=>$c) {
            $tmpArr = explode(' ', $c);             //Create array of each combination (value1, value2, value3)

            //Value3 has to be a double
            $tmpArr[2] *= 2;            

            //Get ascii-value of whole string (without spaces)
            $tc = trim($c);
            $ascValue = getAsciiValueOfString($tc);

            //If sum of array-values is the same as score, add it to outs array
            //Also make sure that ascii-value of string occurence cannot be repeated ('0 1 49' or '0 49 1' is actually same)
            if (array_sum($tmpArr) == $score && !in_array($ascValue, $ascArr)) {        
                $possibleOuts[] = $c . ' double';
                $ascArr[] = $ascValue;
            }

        }

        //Could some more part of outs array (besides last) be a double?
        $doubleOuts = array();
        $do = array();

        foreach($possibleOuts as $value) {
            $tmpArr = explode(' ', $value); 
            $do[0] = $tmpArr[0];
            $do[1] = $tmpArr[1];
            $do[2] = $tmpArr[2];
            $do[3] = $tmpArr[3];

            //Check first value. If first value can be divided into 2 and the second value as well
            //then set double on first value, and reduce second value
            if ($tmpArr[0] % 2 === 0 && $tmpArr[0]>0 && $tmpArr[1] % 2 === 0) {
                $do[0] = $tmpArr[0] . ' double';
                $do[1] = $tmpArr[1] - $tmpArr[0];
            }

            $doubleOuts[] = implode(' ', $do);

        }


        //Merge outs and doubleouts-array
        $posOuts = array_merge($possibleOuts, $doubleOuts);


    // Print it out
    foreach($posOuts as $value) {
        echo $value . ' <br />';
    }



}



//Function for getting value of chars
function getAsciiValueOfString($string)
{
    $ascii = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
    { 
        $ascii += ord($string[$i]); 
    }

    return($ascii);
}

//Recursive functions for getting differet combinations
function getCombinations($arr,$n)
{
     $res = array();

     foreach ($arr as $w)
     {
           if ($n==1) $res[] = $w;
           else
           {
                 $perms = getCombinations($arr,$n-1);

                 foreach ($perms as $p)
                 {
                      $res[] = $w." ".$p;
                 } 
           }
     }


     return $res;
}


?>
```

Output:

```
0 0 25 double
0 2 24 double
0 4 23 double
0 6 22 double
0 8 21 double
0 10 20 double
0 12 19 double
0 14 18 double
0 16 17 double
0 18 16 double
0 20 15 double
0 22 14 double
0 24 13 double
0 26 12 double
0 28 11 double
0 30 10 double
0 32 9 double
0 34 8 double
0 36 7 double
0 38 6 double
0 46 2 double
0 48 1 double
1 19 15 double
1 39 5 double
3 9 19 double
3 19 14 double
3 29 9 double
3 39 4 double
5 19 13 double
5 29 8 double
5 39 3 double
7 19 12 double
7 29 7 double
7 39 2 double
9 19 11 double
9 29 6 double
10 10 15 double
10 12 14 double
10 14 13 double
10 16 12 double
10 18 11 double
10 20 10 double
10 40 0 double
11 19 10 double
13 19 9 double
15 19 8 double
17 19 7 double
19 19 6 double
19 29 1 double
0 0 25 double
0 2 24 double
0 4 23 double
0 6 22 double
0 8 21 double
0 10 20 double
0 12 19 double
0 14 18 double
0 16 17 double
0 18 16 double
0 20 15 double
0 22 14 double
0 24 13 double
0 26 12 double
0 28 11 double
0 30 10 double
0 32 9 double
0 34 8 double
0 36 7 double
0 38 6 double
0 46 2 double
0 48 1 double
1 19 15 double
1 39 5 double
3 9 19 double
3 19 14 double
3 29 9 double
3 39 4 double
5 19 13 double
5 29 8 double
5 39 3 double
7 19 12 double
7 29 7 double
7 39 2 double
9 19 11 double
9 29 6 double
10 double 0 15 double
10 double 2 14 double
10 double 4 13 double
10 double 6 12 double
10 double 8 11 double
10 double 10 10 double
10 double 30 0 double
11 19 10 double
13 19 9 double
15 19 8 double
17 19 7 double
19 19 6 double
19 29 1 double
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my account a couple years ago. If anyone stumbles across this I ended up finishing the code for this and here it is.

1. Updated variable names per @bestprogrammerintheworld suggestion
2. Allow user to put in their preferred finishing dart.
3. Remove duplicates (e.g. '45, 30, double 2' and '30, 45, double 2' will only display once).

(Editor wont break list from code without something here).

```
<?php
$score =$_GET['score'];
$finaldart = $_GET['out'] * 2;
if ($score >170 || $score <=1 ) {
    die('No outs possible');
} else {
    for ($firstdart=60; $firstdart >= 0; $firstdart--) {
        if (
            $firstdart <= 20 || 
            $firstdart == 50 || 
            $firstdart == 25 || 
            ($firstdart % 3 == 0) || 
            ($firstdart <= 40 && $firstdart % 2 == 0)
        ) {
            /*
            if it is less than 20 or equal to, because 20 - 1 on board, 
            if it is less than or equal to 40 and divisible by 2 because it could be a double
            if it is divisible by 3 because it could be a triple
            if it is a double or single bull, no point in checking the double for 60-51 
            */
            for ($seconddart=60; $seconddart >= 0; $seconddart--) {
                if (
                    $seconddart <= 20 || 
                    $seconddart == 50 || 
                    $seconddart == 25 || 
                    ($seconddart % 3 == 0) || 
                    ($seconddart <= 40 && $seconddart % 2 == 0)
                    ) {
                    for ($thirddart=50; $thirddart > 0; $thirddart = $thirddart - 2) {
                        if ($thirddart == 48) {
                            $thirddart = 40;
                        }
                        $outstring = 'Double ' . ($thirddart / 2);
                        if (($thirddart + $seconddart + $firstdart) == $score && (@!in_array($seconddart . ', ' . $firstdart . ', ' . $outstring . "<br />\n", $pouts) && @!in_array($seconddart . ', ' . $firstdart . ', ' . $outstring . "<br />\n", $everyotherout))) {
                            if ($thirddart == $finaldart) {
                                $pouts[] = $firstdart . ', ' . $seconddart . ', ' . $outstring . "<br />\n";
                            } else {
                                $everyotherout[] = $firstdart . ', ' . $seconddart . ', ' . $outstring . "<br />\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
if(!empty($finaldart)) {
    if(!empty($pouts)){
        foreach($pouts as $out) {
            echo $out;
        }
        echo "<br />\n" . 'Every Other Out' . "<br /><br />\n";
    } else { 
        echo 'No preferred outs avaliable.' . "<br />\n";
    }
}
if(!empty($everyotherout)){
    foreach($everyotherout as $out) {
        echo $out;
    }
} else if(empty($pouts)){
    echo 'No outs avaliable.';
}
?>
```